# automated file transfer using php

Tags: php, ssh, file-transfer

I need the info on the following work process and how I can execute it.

I can't share in details on what the work is but here is the work process.

I will have admin panel on one server and user interface on another. Everyday users will log in to admin panel and create images that will be shown on the user interface. This consists of database update and several image files.

Once the work is done, I will need those files to be transferred over to another server. It would be best if it can be done with a click of a button.

All the files will be in one folder and that folder will need to be transferred.

Also the files that are created are close to 100MB so if it is possible can SSH be used to transfer the files automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `exec()` or `system()` you can make calls to the shell directly to transfer in any way you like.  You could use wput, ftp, rsync, scp, etc.

Comment: Be aware that these functions could be disabled, due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec()` or `passthru()` or `system()` and call system functions to transfer the files. rsync over SSH could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('remote.file', 'local.file', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
print_r($sftp->nlist());
?>
```